# Anchor tags in urls & search engines, HOWTO?

Tags: anchor, search-engine

How do I implement anchor tag urls so that search engines crawl my pages? Here's an example from twitter:

In search results it's:
    `http://twitter.com/username`

When I click on it, it redirects me to
`http://twitter.com/#!/username`

How does twitter know when to redirect? Relying on a User-Agent doesn't seem such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter isn't optimizing their site for SEO. They have a special deal with Google so I wouldn't use them as an example. Google has support for hash URLs, which you can read about here https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification.

The main idea is that a URL like `http://www.example.org/#!/my-url` the crawlers convert to `http://www.example.org/?_escaped_fragment_=/my-url`. When Google encounters that URLs it makes a get requests to the alternative URL and will use that content to index it.